# Visual Studio - X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a cross-plataform (Windows / Linux) x64 GUI application, using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

In this 2019 edition we can use Visual Studio to **debug both plataforms (Windows - Native) and Linux - Ubuntu (Running in a Virtual Machine).**

You can see it here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-visual-studio-for-cross-platform-c-development-targeting-windows-and-linux/

So, I followed this tutorial and  I got this GUI example application running and debugging in my Ubuntu 18 VM using Visual Studio 2019 IDE. **Perfect!**

Now, I tried to do my custom GUI application:

To do a cross-plataform GUI, I'm using GLFW 3.3.

Steps:

1. Create a Visual Studio CMake Project
2. Write the C++ code and CMakeLists.txt
3. Add Both VS debug configurations (Windows x64 and Linux x64)
4. Compile and Link (**OK on both** VS Windows and Linux targets)
5. Run (**Ok on both** VS Windows and Linux targets)

But...

When I run it in Windows setup, I got all ok...a GLFW window shows up...**good!**
When I run it in Linux-debug (by Visual Studio), when the VS debuger hits `glfwInit()` line, I got this error:

`Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3`

`Glfw Error 65544: X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing`

So, when I select the Linux debug configuration **I got NO GUI Window in my VM.**

Searching on internet, I saw that is necessary say to Visual Studio **to export the DISPLAY linux enviroment variable inside the launch.vs.json file.**

You can see it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/get-started-linux-cmake?view=vs-2019

Inside my VM Ubuntu, I got `DISPLAY:0`

Then, my launch.vs.json file I wrote:

`"export DISPLAY=:0;${debuggerCommand}"`

or

`"export DISPLAY=:0.0;${debuggerCommand}"`

**Details:**

IF I **manually** go inside my Ubuntu VM, and double-click in the compiled application, it shows up the GLFW window and **all goes Ok!**

**My problem is:**

How can I export the DISPLAY enviroment variable to the Linux VM using Visual Studio 2019 IDE to debug my application that will run inside the Virtual Box (VM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some nice guys of Microsoft C++ Team (thanks Ion, Erika and Elisabeth) help me and I found the solution.

The problem is related with the Visual Studio **automatic generated "launch.json" file.**

What "launch.json" properties **I had to change:**

1- Set a `"name": "helloworld"`. The default value is `" "`.

2- Set `"project": "CMakeLists.txt"`. The default value is `" "`.

3- Set `"projectTarget": "helloworld"`. This property is **not** created automatically by VS 2019.

4- Set `"cwd": "${debugInfo.defaultWorkingDirectory}"`. The default value is `"${debugInfo.defaultRemoteDirectory}"`

5- Add `"export DISPLAY=:0;"` inside pipeArgs

6- Remove the line `"processId: 0"`. With this line, **only the root user** can deploy and debug on Linux.

7- Add a new line inside pipeArgs: `"--tty=${debugInfo.tty}"`. This line is **not** automatically generated when you create a CMake Project VS2019

So pipeArgs is:

```
"pipeArgs": [
          "/s",
          "${debugInfo.remoteMachineId}",
          "/p",
          "${debugInfo.parentProcessId}",
          "/c",
          "export DISPLAY=:0;${debuggerCommand}",
          "--tty=${debugInfo.tty}"
        ]
```