# GLFW can't find X11 display?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, x11, glfw

I can't seem to get GLFWInit's function working, I keep getting the "X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing" error.

I've tried `export DISPLAY=<my_ip>:0.0`
I've tried `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`
I've tried `export DISPLAY=:0`

Basically everything on these stackoverflow articles:

[glfwInit fails inside library X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201348/glfwinit-fails-inside-library-x11-the-display-environment-variable-is-missing)

[Visual Studio - X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743033/visual-studio-x11-the-display-environment-variable-is-missing)

I'm on linux, Manjaro GNOME, I have my GPU drivers installed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

int canvas(size_t width, size_t height) {
    auto init_val = glfwInit();
    auto ptr = "";
    glfwGetError(&ptr);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Canvas", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    canvas(300, 500);
    // while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    //     glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    //     glfwPollEvents();
    // }
    std::cout << window << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output is a window to show up briefly, but instead `ptr` becomes an error string and window is a nullptr.

Comment: Given that you're running Gnome are you sure you aren't running a Wayland session?

Comment: positive @genpfault

Comment: Please describe **precisely** steps invoved in "I export ..." and then steps involved in running your program.

Comment: In a terminal, what `echo $DISPLAY` shows?

Comment: @Bapo: If running in Wayland, then you require experimental Wayland support in GLFW: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/news.html#news_31_wayland – my suggestion: Use X11; that at least does work.